# Would you help me with these verbs?

Tags: direct-speech

Is the statement which I have put below right?

> **The only two of the verbs to be followed immidiately by an indirect**
>   **object are promise and tell.**

**For instance :**

> *She promised/told that she would come.*

Comment: Your two examples are the same?

Comment: @nima_persian please don't mind my saying. Please follow a grammar book first. As for the confusion related to your post I will ask you to search internet for Transitive Intransitive verb topics. Happy learning :)

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not quite correct.  First, you wouldn't leave out the direct object with "told", because it's a transitive verb.  You'll want to read up on transitive and intransitive verbs ([here](http://snarkygrammarguide.blogspot.com/2010/10/verbs-intransitive-vs-transitive.html) is a quick overview): transitive verbs take a direct object, and intransitive verbs do not.  So very often, intransitive verbs are followed by an indirect object.  Some verbs (such as "promise") can be either:

> She ran for her life.
>   She ran a shop on the corner.

Note that the intransitive version in the first example is immediately followed with an indirect object.